# LINQ nested collection

Tags: c#, linq

I have a class that has a sub collection. Something like this:

```
public class Item { 
    public string Type {get;set}
    public Subitem[] {get;set;}
}
```

I know that I can separate and count by Type this way:

```
var count = (from x in items
            group x by x.Type into grouped
            select new {
                typename = grouped.Key,
                count = grouped.Count()
                }).ToDictionary<string, int>(x => x.typename, x => x.count);
```

This will return something like this:

{ type1, 13 }
{ type2, 26 }

and so on.

But how can I count by Subitem?

To return something like:
{ subitem1, 15 }
{ subitem2, 46 }

Comment: Could you please tell us what are numbers behind subitem1 and subitem2 in your example? Are these counts of items or sub items?

Do you want to count number of items having subitem1 in subitems list (array)?

Comment: Yes! These are counts. In the example, there are 15 Items that have subitem1 in the whole collection of Items.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code sample is not legal C#, but suppose you have a collection called `Subitems` in your items - then you can use [`SelectMany()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb345618.aspx) or in query syntax:

```
var count = (from i in items
             from x in i.Subitems
             group x by x into grouped
             select new 
             {
                typename = grouped.Key,
                count = grouped.Count()
              }).ToDictionary(x => x.typename, x => x.count);
```

Or alternatively in method syntax:

```
var countDict = items.SelectMany(x => x.Subitem)
                     .GroupBy(x => x)
                     .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.Count());
```

Comment: Hi @BrokenGlass. What you do is you flatten sub items and counting them. In this case there is no analogy to what the author of question was doing with types. He was grouping by type and counting items (not sub items).

Comment: @achitaka-san: Mhh OP's example led me to believe that's what he wanted - maybe if OP can clarify

Comment: Is it not legal C# because of the names? It is just an example. My names are not Item is "Answer" and Subitems is "Devices". The type grouping was just an example. This code solved my problem. Thanks guys.